# Unary Operator and Unterminated string literal issue

Tags: swift, xcode, string-literals, unary-operator

I'm looking for some guidance and/or assistance with these 2 errors I have on the code for the the password registration/login of an Swift App I'm working on.

I'm a little stuck as I have tried everything I can think of and find online but I jsut can not seem to crack this issue. I did quite a bit of work using Swift 1 & 2, but I think this may be an issue related to the syntax of Swift 4 and the changes from 3/4 onwards.

Any assitance would be gratefully received ;-)

```
//
//  RegisterPageViewController.swift
//  v2.0.2
//
//  Created by Alex Jeffries on 18/07/2018.
//

import UIKit

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet weak var userFullNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userMobileNumberField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userName = userFullNameTextField.text;
    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userMobile = userMobileNumberField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

    // Check for empty fields
    if(userEmail?.isEmpty)!, ||(userPassword?.isEmpty)!,||    (userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty)!
    {

        //Display alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required");
        return;

    }

    //Check if passwords match
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword)
    {
        //Display an alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords do not match");

        return;

    }

    // Store data

    // Display alert message with confirmation

}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{

    _ = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage,  preferredStyle:
        UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    _ = UIAlertAction(title:"OK', style:UIalertActionStyle.Default,  handler:nil);

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)

}

}
```

Comment: `"OK'` -> `"OK"`

Comment: Remove the commas from your `if(userEmail?.isEmpty)!, ...` statement and add whitespace around `||` operator.  Note: `(userEmail?.isEmpty)!` is the same as `userEmail!.isEmpty` and both with crash if `userEmail` is `nil`.

Comment: Lose the `;`'s.  Swift isn't C.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Unfortunately, that has generated 4 additional errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors:

1. This :

   `if(userEmail?.isEmpty)!, ||(userPassword?.isEmpty)!,|| 
   (userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty)!`

Should be:

```
if (userEmail?.isEmpty)!, (userPassword?.isEmpty)!, (userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty)!
```

It would be better to avoid crashing with forced-unwrapping strings and go for something like this:

```
if userEmail != "", userPassword != "", userRepeatPassword != ""
```

Keep in mind that comparing an email to an empty string wouldn't be sufficient for a valid registration. And even a string with white spaces is not `empty`.

2. and don't forget to use double quotation marks with string literals:

   `let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK', style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,  handler:nil);`

Should be:

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,  handler:nil);
```

Assuming that `userName` and `userMobile` will be used elsewhere, the following code should compile without errors:

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userName = userFullNameTextField.text;
    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userMobile = userMobileNumberField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

    // Check for empty fields
    if userEmail != "", userPassword != "", userRepeatPassword != ""
    {

        //Display alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required");
        return;

    }

    //Check if passwords match
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword)
    {
        //Display an alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords do not match");

        return;

    }

    // Store data

    // Display alert message with confirmation

}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage,  preferredStyle:
        UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,  handler:nil);

        myAlert.addAction(okAction);

    self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)

}
```